# Sci-fi movie about a laser weapon that eventually selfdestructs

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Looking for a movie I watched about ten years ago.

Main story line: not much I remember, but one of the main characters is a kid whose dad got locked up in some kind of weird brain research institution. Kid wants his dad back. I mostly remember the loose scenes though and some descriptions:

- The laser gun: it looked like a large-ish pistol, made of what looked like metallic plastic. The kid described is a looking like a toy. It shoots red beams which can reflect off glass and mirrors, but for instance burn a clean hole through a person. It also has a selfdestruct button which causes it to blow up with beams of white light after a delay.
- The dad of the kid is held in some kind of "virtual reality" at times, we can see sometimes from his point of view and sometimes from a screen next to the bed he is strapped in. There's a scene of him "returning home" with the kid and they have an argument of sorts and then the kid just starts repeating "I hate you", the simulation loops at that point.
- At some point the gun backfires on one of the bad guys shooting it - someone places a mirror so the blast bounces a few times and then returns multiplied to the guy. 4 or 5 holes.
- Somewhere close to the end, right before the kid's dad is rescued, there's a scientist wanting to drill into his brain since no other way was successful for whatever it was that they wanted (I don't remember what, I think some kind of codes or blueprints). They draw a circle on his head and planning to use a regular looking drill.
- After the rescue, they set the gun to self destruct and later you see the outside of the facility, white beams shoot up and to the sides and everything explodes.

I think it was an 80's movie but could be a decade earlier or later.

It is definitely not Laserblast, and no amount of googling/IMDB/TVTropes has helped me. I've posted on Reddit and somewhere else, been looking for the movie for years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [The Secret Agent Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Agent_Club) from 1996 with Hulk Hogan.

> Ray Chase, an agent so secret even his son doesn't know. When he brings home a high-powered laser gun he stole, the theft victim sends her henchmen to capture Ray and get the gun back. But Ray's son escapes with the gun and then devises a plan to rescue his dad.

Everything you mentioned is in there (the VR simulation where his son keeps saying he hates him, their plan to drill into his head etc.) Here's the trailer:

Comment: Holy crap, that is it! I've even found it on youtube in its full so I was able to scrub for some scenes. It's definitely correct, but it's funny how there are some small differences between my memory and the movie. After all these years, the search is over. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Raiders of the Living Dead"(1986)?

I haven't seen this one, but I know it has a kid making a laser gun out of a cd player? Here is the IMDB page.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138050/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1

Comment: Nope, not it. Gun looks differently and there were no zombies.